# Examples not working in downloaded Extjs 6.2.0 framework

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I have a licensed version of extjs 6.2.0. I tried to run examples by opening *index.html* in folder *ext-6.2.0\examples* . The similar page gets opened like shown in the link http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/examples/, but when I try to go further by clicking on options shown on page say *Kitchen Sink (Classic)*, instead of showing page like http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/examples/kitchensink/#all, directory structure (...\ext-6.2.0\examples\kitchensink) gets opened in browser.

Comment: I suggest you to see the documentation of creating app and how to run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some kind of web server to make this work. Luckily enough, Sencha Cmd has a built in one. So, assuming you have Sencha Cmd installed, here are the steps to get this working:

1. from your terminal navigate to the *ext-6.2.0* folder (`cd ext-6.2.0`);
2. from there, run the `sencha web start` command;
3. open the address where the server has started (by default should be *http://localhost:1841/*)

Comment: I followed the same steps and got the following error: _HTTP ERROR 404 Problem accessing /kitchensink/. Reason: Not Found_

Comment: Do you have a _ext-6.2.0/examples/kitchensink_ folder?

Comment: yes, I have. Following are the folders/files that exist in _examples_ folder: _calendar, classic, feed-viewer, kitchensink, resources, examples.js, index.html, main.css, main.js_

Comment: And you run the `sencha web start` command from _ext-6.2.0_, and not from _ext-6.2.0/examples_? If you do so, at what point to you get the 404 error?

Comment: There was some cache related issue. Above mentioned steps are correct.